# Adding a Logo to the left of the Name and Description in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The theme I have selected in Wordpress is very simple with not a lot of customizations built in. I am trying to add a small logo to appear to the left of the Name and Description at the top left of the page.

I have uploaded the file and have been able to succesfully add the following code

```css
         
    
<img src = "http://www.pixelbip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/PixelBip-Icon.png" height="70" width="70"/>
```

But that just puts the logo at the top left then the Name and Description appear below the logo.

Also. I am not very experienced with PHP or CSS. I know a little bit only.

Here is the contents of my header.php file

```css
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package Readly
 * @since Readly 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />



<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action('before'); ?>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
 <div id="header-wrapper">
  <hgroup>
   <div id="hgroup-wrapper">
    <div id="hgroup-wrapper2">
     <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
     <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
    </div>
   </div>
  </hgroup>

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
   <div id="site-navigation-wrapper">
    <div id="site-navigation-wrapper2">
     <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e('Menu', 'readly'); ?><span>m</span></h1>
     <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Skip to content', 'readly'); ?>"><?php _e('Skip to content', 'readly'); ?></a></div>

     <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => false)); ?>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
 </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->

<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
 <div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Can anyone spell out for a newbie how i can add the code I need?

One more thing I need to add. I need to do this change to the Child theme header.php so that future updates to the theme don't mess up my logo.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Your code snippets add nothing to the question.  You don't need a snippet to show code, just 4 spaces to format a line as code.

Comment: Where have you added the <img> tag? I can't see it in the header.php file. I'm guessing it's in another file, is it? Also, you should add this: `alt=""` to you image tag. It can go in right after width and before the closing tag. The full line would be this: `<img src = "http://www.pixelbip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/PixelBip-Icon.png" height="70" width="70" alt=""/>`

Comment: Mike. Sorry about the code snippets. This is literally my first post here. I was trying to be thorough.

Comment: tdrsam - I removed the <img> before posting the code as it was not working. it was originally posted above the lines. <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
     <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>